# Copy-Paste row whenever certain cell changed

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am an App Script newbie. Recently I am tasked to script a Sheet that is used by many users.

So the sheet has a 5-column table. Let's say A2:E. The columns A:D are dynamically imported from other sources that changed dynamically and imported, merged, and sorted by Column A (Query + Importrange). While the users of the sheet are only allowed to make changes to column E.

Like this:

| Column A | Column B | Column D | Column D | Column E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| PIC1 | xxxx | xxxx | xxxx |  |
| PIC2 | xxxx | xxxx | xxxx |  |
| PIC2 | xxxx | xxxx | xxxx |  |

Column E is initially empty.

So I am required to build a script that:

1. Copy a row every time its column E is updated, then paste it into another Sheet named "Log"
2. Add a timestamp into the Log sheet for each new row added.
3. Whenever the A:D changed from the new update and sort, the data in Column E should "follow" its former A:D row data into their new row.

Is it achievable? Using App Script?
I don't mind if there would be helper column(s) involved.

If it isn't practical, are there better alternatives?

I thank you in advance for helping me solve this problem. :cheers:

I did some scripting and even ask ChatGPT to optimize it, however, it didn't work. Here is the script optimized by ChatGPT:

```
function makeLogRekon() {
  const gs = SpreadsheetApp.openById('xxxxxx');
  const sourceSheet = gs.getSheetByName('User');
  const sourceRange = sourceSheet.getRange('A2:E');

  const logSheet = gs.getSheetByName('Log');
  const logLastRow = logSheet.getLastRow();

  const data = sourceRange.getValues();
  const numRows = data.length;

  for (let i = 0; i < numRows; i++) {
    if (data[i][data[i].length - 1] !== '') { // Checking the last column (E) for changes
      const rowToCopy = sourceSheet.getRange(i + 1, 1, 1, 5); // Range A:E for the changed row
      const destination = logLastRow + 1;
      rowToCopy.copyTo(logSheet.getRange(destination, 1)); // Paste the row to the Log sheet
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. I have 2 questions. 1. About `Add timestamp into the Log sheet for each the new row added.`, where is the new row added? 2. I cannot understand `Whenever the A:D changed from new update and sort, the data in Column E should "follow" it's former A:D row data into their new row.`. First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: 1. So for example, cell E3 is changed by a user, the script should copy A3:E3 into another sheet named 'Log' then Append the new row into it.
After the row appended, for example, at 'Log'!A5:E5, there should be timestamp in the cell 'Log'!F5.

Comment: 2. If the structure of the table changed, for example:

A | B | C | D | E
person 1 | x | y | z | xxx
person 3 | p | q | r | nnn

then changed into:
A | B | C | D | E
person 1 | x | y | z | xxx
person 2 | a | b | c | mmm
person 3 | p | q | r | nnn

So the person 3 row moved from row 2:2 into row 3:3
I wanted the nnn stay intact with the person 3
(the A:D are dynamic data from Importranges and Queries, however the E by default, are not dynamic)

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, about an answer to my 1st question, `the new row added` means the appended row to "log" sheet by copying a row from your showing table. Is my understanding correct? If my understanding is correct, I think that your 1st and 2nd questions can be resolved. But, about your 3rd question, unfortunately, I cannot still understand from your reply. I apologize for this. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand your 3 questions, I would like to think of a solution.

Comment: Yes it is correct.
The 3rd question arise from my experience. I had a table let's say, A:D that dynamically changed according whenever its sources files are changed. While the in its right, I made a column to add information for each row. 
Imagine this: Row 2 consist of A2, B2, C2, D2, Row 3: A3, B3, C3, D3. Then I added information E2 to row 2, and E3 to row 3, 
so A2, B2, C2, D2, E2 
so A3, B3, C3, D3, E3
However when the table changed and come A1, B1, C1, D1 into row 2, the E didnt move: so it became:
A1, B1, C1, D1, E2
A2, B2, C2, D2, E3
A3, B3, C3, D3, 

So i want to prevent it

Comment: i am sorry, the comment dont allow new line break, so the supposed illustration of table got flattened.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I understood that I could correctly understand your 2nd question. About your 3rd question, from `A:D that dynamically changed according whenever its sources files are changed.`, what are `sources files`? Is your showing table in your question constructed from multiple Google Spreadsheets? And also, are those multiple Google Spreadsheets manually edited? And, when those Spreadsheets are manually edited, do you want to reorder the rows of column "E"? If my understanding is correct, how should we correspond to each row of "A;D" and "E"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
function onMyInstallableEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName() == "User" && e.range.columnStart == 5 && e.range.rowStart > 1) {
    let lss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("ssid");
    let gs = lss.getSheetByName("Log");
    let vs = sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 1 , 1, 5).getValues();
    gs.getRange(gs.getLastRow() + 1, 1, vs.length, vs[0].length).setValues(vs);
  } 
}
```

You will need to create and installable onEdit trigger named onMyInstallableEdit

Comment: Hello, is this the full code or only part of it? If this only the part, may you elaborate further? Thank you.

Comment: Did you create the trigger?

Comment: Yes, I did and it works as needed. Thank you very much. 